# How do I capture light trails at night with a smartphone?

Tags: long-exposure, photography-basics, smartphone

How can I capture light trails from passing cars and other moving lights with my smartphone? I am using an iPhone 6S.

Here is an example of what I want to capture:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create long exposure images with my Ipad or my Android Smartphone?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/74794/how-can-i-create-long-exposure-images-with-my-ipad-or-my-android-smartphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need to set long exposure, likely several seconds, and set your aperture and ISO appropriately to achieve correct exposure. For long exposures you need to make sure that your camera is absolutely steady. Tripod is usually used for this purpose.

You would need an app that can control the ISO, exposure time and aperture.

Comment: What's the Best Free App for iPhone 6s for this?

Answer (score -1):

[Video Tutorial Using Slow Shutter App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6P18nr5ud7w)

https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/4wv6d6/what_is_the_best_long_exposure_photography_app/d6ab2vb/?st=iurnvcq9&sh=c2042fe5

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.